# Influencing/Setting tx.gasprice

Tags: solidity, remix, gas-price

I am currently trying to solve a security challenge.

Thereby, as the last step in order to solve it, I have to make sure that the following require is true:

```
modifier filter() {
    require(tx.gasprice % 2245 == 0);
    _;
}
function hack() public payable filter {
    payable(tx.origin).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

But I am currently struggeling finding a way of how to influence/set the `tx.gasprice` in order to fulfil the require.
Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Context: I am calling the function hack using another contract (which is required in order to solve previous steps of the challenge).

Answer (score 0):

The gas price can only be set externally, when building the transaction.
If you have more context on how you are preparing the transaction we could help you do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The function `hack` I call with a helper contract.     
`function call() public {firewall.hack{gas: gas, value: 0.011 ether}();}`
And the `call` function of the helper contract I call as follows: `helper.methods.call().send({from: myAddress});` using web3.js

Comment: If you use web3.js, then you need to set the gas price from here before signing and sending the transaction. Hint: look at the `gasPrice` parameter https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id35

Comment: I tried to call it as follows: `helper.methods.call().send({from: myAddress, gasPrice: '2245'});` but `tx.gasprice` seems to still be equal to `1`.

Comment: This looks correct to me. Are you able to get the receipt and confirm that the `gasPrice` is not the expected one by subscribing to the "receipt" event as written in the examples https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id37 ?